# XFCE doesn't display menu

Tags: 14.04

I have lost controll over the workspace, the icons on the left have dissapered, I am unable to change the background and rightclicking mouse on screen dos'nt work eighter.

I was trying to put some books on my ipad, it failed - books are there but they dont show up on bookshelf.

After rebooting (trying to get Calibre to catch the ipad) the background image showed at login screen, but disapered when loging in - replaced with some big pixelated garbage.

Loging in as gues, everything worked, and I could change background and interact with the screen  --  Rebooting and loging in as my self left the background picture,but the rest is still absent.

Which local settings should i correct? Or reinstall which packages?
I use ubuntu studio 64 on a Dell latitude.

Comment: Its XFCE thats broke, menu works but loging out leaves you with a blank screen - no login! Have to Ctrl Alt F1 and login in terminal mode, chvt 7 to graphics mode and login again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was the local settings on my account that went haywire!
Creating a new user and mooving my nonhidden files(no configurations etc) to the new homedir, and chainging ownership solved this anoying problem.
After some cleanup and updates everything is back to normal.
Even usb support in virtualbox works now, that didnt before.
Installing skype from cannonical also works!